# Can I use named pipes inside containers?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, named-pipes

I am trying to use named pipes for inter-process communication inside a docker container but am getting "not found" errors when trying to read/write. Does docker for windows support named pipes? The software's been released and I know it works fine in VMs. I just can't find anything saying yes or no that containers on windows support named pipes.

I've got an IIS application with a named pipe binding installed inside the container along with a client application also inside the container trying to communicate via net.pipe://localhost. My run command looks like this

```
docker run -it -m 2GB -p 80:80 --network External company/appserver
```

The error message is

> The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/WCFSvc/WCF.svc' could not be
>   found on your local machine

Comment: Can you...maybe share an example of exactly what you're trying to do? And the specific code you're running, and the exact error messages that result?

Comment: @larsks I didn't feel like that is relevant because I'm using released software that I know works. I just want to know if there is an official declaration that docker for windows does not support named pipes.

Comment: " I didn't feel like that is relevant ". I'm afraid you're mistaken.  Support (or not!) for named pipes has very little to do with Docker itself and has much more to do with exactly how you are starting your containers and where you are locating your named pipes.

Comment: @larsks Details added.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount named pipes into Docker containers, but this only works on Windows Server 1709 and later. I put an example in my blog post: https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine friism/jenkins
```